# Pandas Groupby Transforming Matrices Not Affecting Groupby Object

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following simple groupby:

```
  results_by_lab = results.groupby(lambda x : x.laboratory, 1)
  for k, v in results_by_lab:
    v = v.sum(axis=1)
  for k, v in results_by_lab:
    print k
    print v
```

The sum has no effect on the groupby object.

I've been getting around this issue by loading the data into a Python dictionary, but this surely can't be the right way to do things.

How should I be saving the transformations in the groupby object?

EDIT:

To clarify, my difficulty is that sometimes my transformation rely on the value of the headers.
The above code doesn't demonstrate this, but the following does:

```
  results_by_lab = results.groupby(lambda x : x.laboratory, 1)
  for k, v in results_by_lab:
    v = v.sum(axis=1)
    v = v.apply(lambda x : adjust_cfm_for_laboratory_parameters(x, k))
```

Can this sort of modification be done through a transformation where the transformation of the dataframe (v) relies on its key?

Comment: docs are here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation; not exactly sure what you are trying to do, maybe post your example frame and what you are tring to do.

Answer (score 0):

The sum "has no effect" because `v = v.sum(axis=1)` does not actually update each group. It redefines the variable `v` and subsequently overwrites it on each iteration of the loop. Your `GroupBy` object, `results_by_lab`, is never changed.

Happily, pandas makes it very easy to do what it seems you want to do.

```
total_by_lab = results_by_lab.sum()
```

will give the sum over each group. Then of course you can print `total_by_lab` if you wish.

More generally, if you want to transform the groups of a `GroupBy` object with any arbitrary function, use the methods apply, transform, or filter. See the docs linked by Jeff above to understand the distinctions between these three.

Comment: i've edited the original post to clarify some of my difficulty.

i'm going to be looking into whether or not i can express everything else as a transformation, though, thanks!

Comment: i've had no success using transform, apply, or aggregate to accomplish my goal. :-/

Comment: Open a new question, because it's really a separate question that you are asking, and provide the simplest possible "toy" data that demonstrates what you have and what you want.

Comment: sounds like a plan!
i think i might actually move this to the pandas github issues and see what they have to say about it.
i've asked a few people outside of stackoverflow and it really seems to be a lack of feature (or a lack of idiomatic method on my part, but this really seems like something pandas should be able to do) more than an error.